# Card game where you're dealt two role cards you keep hidden

Tags: identify-this-game

I played a game a couple of months ago that was pretty minimalist. Everyone (6+ players) was dealt two cards that they kept hidden. Each had a role, I think some included Assassin, Baron or Duke(?), Courtesan(?). During each person's turn, you could do some basic action, an improved action permitted by your hidden role cards, or bluff another action. You lose when both your cards are revealed through people calling your bluff or they're killed.

The game had a short name that I can't for the life of me seem to figure out. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The game you're thinking of is called [The Resistance: Coup](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/131357/coup).

It was originally a kickstarter game that has lots of different publishers/distributors depending on what country you're in, but it's available from Amazon either way.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a very similar game called Love Letter. Probably not what you're looking for, but I thought I'd mention it.